# Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out the distribution by hour of the day for each of the messages

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, tuples

> 10.2 Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out the distribution by hour of the day for each of the messages. You can pull the hour out from the 'From ' line by finding the time and then splitting the string a second time using a colon.
>   From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
>   Once you have accumulated the counts for each hour, print out the counts, sorted by hour as shown below.

My Code:

```
fname = input("Enter file:")
fhandle = open(fname)
dic={}
for line in fhandle:
    if not line.startswith("From "):
        continue
    else:
        line=line.split()
        line=line[5]  # accesing the list using index and splitting it 
        line=line[0:2]
    for bline in line:
        dic[bline]=dic.get(bline,0)+1   # Using this line we created a dictionary having keys and values
#Now it's time to access the dictionary and sort in some way.
lst=[]
for k1,v1 in dic.items(): # dictionary er key value pair access korar jonno items method use kora hoyechhe
    lst.append((k1,v1)) # dictionary er keys and corresponding values ke lst te append korlam
lst.sort()   #lst take sort korlam. sorting is done through key
#print(lst)
for k1,v1 in lst:  # we are able to access this list using key value pair as it was basically a dictionary before, It is just appended
    print(k1,v1)

#print(dic)
    #print(dic)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
10 3
11 6
14 1
15 2
16 4
17 2
18 1
19 1
```

My Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk0Lq.png)

I don't understand what's going wrong.

Comment: *line = line[0:2]* will get (for example) the string '09'. 
The for loop immediately afterwards will look for items in the line - in this case, it will split the string into two separate characters - '0' and '9'. Remove the for command, keep the line below at the same indentation, and rename the last instance of line to bline

Answer (score 1):

**Working Code. Break down the code in to simple form as much i can. So it will be easy to understand for you.**

```
d = dict()
lst = list()

fname = input('enter the file name : ')
try:
    fopen = open(fname,'r')
except:
    print('wrong file name !!!')

for line in fopen:
    
    stline = line.strip()
    
    if stline.startswith('From:'):
        continue
    elif stline.startswith('From'):
        spline = stline.split()
        
        time = spline[5]
        tsplit = time.split(':')
        
        t1 = tsplit[0].split()
        
        for t in t1:
            if t not in d:
                d[t] = 1
            else:
                d[t] = d[t] + 1

for k,v in d.items():
    lst.append((k,v))
lst = sorted(lst)

for k,v in lst:
    print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
emailcount = dict()
for line in handle:
    if not line.startswith("From "): continue
    line = line.split()
    line = line[1]
    emailcount[line] = emailcount.get(line, 0) +1
bigcount = None
bigword = None
for word,count in emailcount.items():
    if bigcount == None or count > bigcount:
        bigcount = count
        bigword = word
print(bigword, bigcount)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

counts = {}
for line in handle:
    word = line.split()
    if len(word) < 3 or word[0] != "From" : continue
    full_hour = word[5]
    hour = full_hour.split(":")
    hour = str(hour[:1])
    hour = hour[2:4]
    if hour in counts :
        counts[hour] = 1 + counts[hour]
    else :
        counts.update({hour:1})
lst = list()
for k, v in counts.items():
    new_tup = (k, v)
    lst.append(new_tup)
 
lst = sorted(lst)    
for k, v in lst:
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: It might be worth providing information as to how, and why your answer helps the OP with their question.

Answer (score 0):

```
counts=dict()
fill=open("mbox-short.txt")
for line in fill :
    if line.startswith("From "):
        x=line.split()
        b=x[5]
        y=b.split(":")
        f=y[0]
        counts[f]=counts.get(f,0)+1
l=list()
for k,v in counts.items():
    l.append((k,v))
l.sort()
for k,v in l:
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I listen carefully in the online lessons, This is my code by what i learned in class. I think it will be easy for you to understand.

```
fn = input('Please enter file: ')
if len(fn) < 1: fn = 'mbox-short.txt'
hand = open(fn)

di = dict()

for line in hand:
    ls = line.strip()
    wds = line.split()
    if 'From' in wds and len(wds) > 2:

        hours = ls.split()
        hour = hours[-2].split(':')
        ch = hour[0]

        di[ch] = di.get(ch, 0) + 1

tmp = list()
for h,t in di.items():
    newt = (h,t)
    tmp.append(newt)

tmp = sorted(tmp)
for h,t in tmp:
    print(h,t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1:
    name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

counts = dict()

for line in handle:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line.startswith("From ") : continue
    line = line.split()
    hr = line[5].split(":")
    hr = hr[0:1]
    for piece in hr:
        counts[piece] = counts.get(piece,0) + 1


lst = list()

for k,v in counts.items():
    lst.append((k,v))
lst = sorted(lst)

for k,v in lst:
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
fname = input("Enter file:")
fhandle = open(fname)
dic={}
for line in fhandle:
    if not line.startswith('From '):
        continue
    else:
        line=line.split()
        line=line[5]  # accesing the list using index and splitting it
        line=line.split(':')
        bline=line[0]
    #for bline in line:
        #print(bline)
        dic[bline]=dic.get(bline,0)+1   # Using this line we created a     
dictionary having keys and values
#Now it's time to access the dictionary and sort in some way.
lst=[]
for k1,v1 in dic.items(): # dictionary er key value pair access korar     jonno items method use kora hoyechhe
    lst.append((k1,v1)) # dictionary er keys and corresponding values ke         lst te append korlam
lst.sort()   #lst take sort korlam. sorting is done through key
#print(lst)
for k1,v1 in lst:  # we are able to access this list using key value pair     as it was basically a dictionary before, It is just appended
    print(k1,v1)

#print(dic)
    #print(dic)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# ask the user for a filename
file_name = input('Enter a filename: ')
# to facilitate testing, I don't want to type filename each time
if len(file_name) < 1: file_name = 'mbox-short.txt'
# try opening the file
try:
    file_handle = open(file_name)
# if file can't be opened, terminate.
except:
    print('Invalid File')
    quit()
# histogram for the hours
counts = dict()
# loop through each line in the file
for line in file_handle:
    # make each line a list of words
    words = line.rstrip().split()
    # if the line is empty, skip it
    if len(words) == 0:
        continue
    # if the line starts with from
    if words[0] == 'From':
        # time string is always at index 5
        timeStr = words[5]
        # find the col position
        colPos = timeStr.find(':')
        # hour would be anything before the col position
        hours = timeStr[:colPos]
        # populate the histogram: if hour is present, increment its value, if not add it to histogram
        counts[hours] = counts.get(hours, 0) + 1
# create a new sorted list in asc. order, based on hour, and append tuples as (hour, value) for every (hour, value) pair
temp_list = sorted([(k, v) for (k, v) in counts.items()])
# print the hour and its value
for (k, v) in temp_list:
    print(k, v)
```